# How can I check if a DAG file is corrupted?

Tags: mining, dag

When mining it's very common for a DAG to become corrupted. To resolve the problem deleting the file and restarting the miner is required.

I'm working on a miner manager to control RIGs and one of the features I want to include is to check if a DAG was corrupted instead of deleting it every X hours.

At this moment I'm only reading "REJECTED" on proxy which can be a cause of corrupted DAG.

So, there is any way (code/commandline) to check if the current DAG file is corrupted?

Comment: Are you mining on Dwarf pool? I got the same problem.

Comment: corrupted DAG will happen in many situation independently of the pool, an electricity cut-off is a possible one

Answer (score 3):

The solution I found was to parse my wallet's page on dwarfpool looking for the string "DAG corrupted" in its content with a little Node.JS script. It should work with any pool.

Obviously if you do not write code it's not that easy. [GoldMiner](http://goldminer.io) does check DAG corruption and automatically restarts mining, it has a cool interface, great for non-coders imho.

Comment: exactly. Shares must be submitted with an old dag, so that the pool knows if it is corrupted. Goldminer is a good solution indeed for several reasons

Answer (score 2):

I think what you can do is to remove your current DAG files and your miner will download it again.

DAG files in OSX and Linux are here: ~/.ethash
DAG files in Windows are here: \~\AppData\Ethash

Comment: deleting the DAGs its the current solution, but you need to see in the miner proxy or the pool to REJECTED or some other warning, until that you lose precious hours of mining, so i want to make some tool to detect inmediatly this problem, then stop proxy and miner, delete dags and restart all again, but first i need to find a code way to detect this independlty of pool, until now its reading in realtime the log from the proxy

Comment: You can have a script to frequently check your log. If you detect REJECTED message then you delete the DAG, reset the miner.